# Any way to access KML files - when using new google.maps.KmlLayer() - via WampServer

Tags: google-maps, kml

The documentation states that KML files need to be publicly hosted on the internet so they can be accessed by Google's servers to find and retrieve the content.

The code for access is the following:

```
new google.maps.KmlLayer(source, options)
```

When the source is the following the program happily works:

```
var source = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/kml/westcampus.kml';
```

When the source is simply the following:

```
var source = 'westcampus.kml';
```

being located in the root directory of the WampServer program on a PC it does not work.

Is there a means / program which will allow Google's servers to access a KML file located on a PC rather than have the KML file located on a publicly hosted web site?

Comment: If you are using KmlLayer, the file **must** be on a publicly available web server (as scaisEdge indicates in his answer).  The way your question is written, his answer is correct.  If you are open to other options, you can look at third party KML parsers, but for complex KML there may be performance issues.

Comment: At last - somebody indicates there are third-party KML parsers! Would you care  to suggest the names of some of the better ones.

Comment: Your question specifically asks about KmlLayer.  Recommending third party libraries is off topic for StackOverflow, but this has come up many times before, did you do any research?

Comment: I have to ask whether you are a lawyer in your spare time? It makes a lot of sense to offer alternatives when the Google route is not an option. Instead of blindly following the dictum of being off-topic, it would be great if answers given showed flexibility and creativity, allowing a solution in some form to be given.

Comment: Message for geocodezip. I think you are talking a load of nonsense. On 28-12-12 you responded to a question concerning geoxml3 - goto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074092/loading-kml-layer-on-google-map-using-geoxml3. The bottom line is that if you are not prepared to assist, then say nothing!

Answer (score 2):

You could consider to utilize the following third-party libraries to access locally hosted KML files:

1)[**geoxml3 library**](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) - KML processor for the Google Maps JavaScript API V3

Example

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
  });

  var parser = new geoXML3.parser({map: map});
  parser.parse('westcampus.kml');
}
```

[Working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/32FoX92uLfxVzK3zL6kG?p=preview)

2)[**kmlmapparser**](https://code.google.com/p/kmlmapparser/) - A Google Maps API Extension for parsing KML files:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
  });



  var xml = new KmlMapParser({ map: map,
                           kml: 'westcampus.kml',
                });

}
```

3)Another option would be to *convert KML into GeoJSON* and utilize [Google Maps Data API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-simple) for displaying data:

[ogr2ogr web client](http://ogre.adc4gis.com/) one of the most popular online tool for converting files into GeoJSON format. Once the KML file is converted, the data could be displayed on map as demonstrated below:

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: { lat: 37.86047, lng: -122.536226 }
    });
    map.data.loadGeoJson('westcampus.json');
}
```

[Working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/5cnM03f5SgHQJWiz4HAe?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the two options. When the working examples for both were tried, only a heading was displayed - not the youTube clip as expected. When I did my own implementation of geoxml3 the clips were displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't accessing to local kml using google maps api. 
For use in google maps the kml must be located in an accessible server e not in local.

This is form google doc.

> Overview
>
> The Google Maps API supports the KML and GeoRSS data formats for displaying geographic information. These data formats are displayed on
>   a map using a KmlLayer object, whose constructor takes the URL of a
>   publicly accessible KML or GeoRSS file.

**the constructor take the URL of a publicly accessible KML.**

Then for yoour need you must place your kml in a publicly accessible server

Comment: All you have done with your answer is to repeat what I have said in the question. With all due respect your contribution is worthless.

Comment: @havelly this if for google developer and from some year of google mapping. if you want use kml inside your google maps you  must place the kml on a accessible server not in localhost or equivalent.. I hope this is clear and useful. For store you kml you can use any kind of public internet accessible resource.

Comment: I try sometime to give my contribution hoping that my contribution is useful and welcome,

Comment: I do not wish to appear ungracious but a little bit of lateral thinking would be great. Perhaps there is a way of accessing a KML file on the localhost without using Google.

Comment: Not a problem, but many of us have tried unsuccessfully to do so (some very highly skilled, experienced so much that if there was a solution it would be very popular on SO). What we do know is that you can not use in  localhost KML  with google maps. The reason is very simple google maps services can not be used offline. If you want to use the google maps with klm you always have to store it a server accessible via the Internet in this way  google can access to the data and render the result to your application. If you want to work offline, you can't use google maps, but can use Google Earth